# Mutter cause crash down

Tags: 18.04, mutter

If I had to upgrade the package 'mutter', the system will be stuck before login, and here is the screenshot.

[image: crashdown]
[image: related package]

VM: VMware® Workstation 14 Pro 14.1.3 build-9474260

Host OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: Hi John!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please try hitting the ESC key during startup and then take a screenshot of that?  It should show the actual startup messages rather than just the purple Ubuntu screen.

Comment: I had tried to record the boot process but looks like all of the info indicates OK before stuck at the purple Ubuntu screen. I will try it again and catch some possible screenshot with fault.